# space validation need quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, trim

JS:

```
var KEYS = { SPACE: 32 };
var str = $('#id_phone_daytime').val();

$("#id_phone_daytime").keyup(function(e) {
    $.trim(str)
    $('#id_phone_daytime').val(str);
    if (e.keyCode == KEYS.SPACE) {
       alert("No space please")
    }
});
```

html:

No space please

The above code is for validating white space for a single input field. It is working fine, but in my application I have 8 more input fields with different ids. I want to validate white space validation for these 8 input fields also.

How to implement the same functionality with minimum amount of code?

Comment: Note that [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) doesn't alter the value of its argument. It instead returns the revised value, which will need to be stored: `str = $.trim(str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `id` selector (which has to be unique) use a `class` selector, which can be used to group elements. Try this:

```
var KEYS = { SPACE: 32 };

$(".no-spaces").keyup(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($.trim($this.val()));

    if (e.keyCode == KEYS.SPACE) {
        alert("No space please");
    }
});
```

All you need to do now is add `class="no-spaces"` to the relevant inputs.

Answer (score 2):

```
var KEYS = { SPACE: 32 };
$(".no-spaces").keyup(function(e) {
    this.value=$.trim(this.value);
    if (e.keyCode == KEYS.SPACE) {
        alert("No space please");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign multiple selector using class, for example

```
<input type="text" class="validate_white_space">
```

and use this class like below.

```
var str = $('.validate_white_space').val();

$(".validate_white_space").keyup(function(e) {
    $.trim(str)
    $('#id_phone_daytime').val(str);
    if (e.keyCode == KEYS.SPACE) {
        alert("No space please");
    }
});
```

Comment: Getting `val()` on a collection of elements will only give you the first value.